# Prevent type being inferred as too narrow with strictFunctionTypes = true

Tags: typescript

I have the following code snippet:

```js
class Foo<T> {
  constructor(public value: T, public fn: (value: Foo<T>) => void) {}
}

const foo = new Foo(5, (v: Foo<number>) => {});
foo.value = 100;
```

When `strictFunctionTypes = true`, this code produces an error, because typescript infers the type of `foo` as `Foo<5>`. With `strictFunctionTypes = false` this code does what I want it to (i.e. infers the type of `foo` as `Foo<number>`).

This problem can be fixed by adding a type annotation when constructing the `foo` instance (i.e. `const foo = new Foo<number>(...);`), or by turning off `strictFunctionTypes`, but is there a better way?

Comment: Remove explicit type annotation from `v` and it will be inferred properly https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVAfNA3gKGtY8AdhAC4BOArsCfGQBQAOFARiAJbDQBuYIFApgC5oKADTQmrDtABmhYXR58hcRKjQBKaAF4MXeGwAmWzAF9s57AWIlZiHdEL8A7qvh0ArOK46MZjQDcQA

Comment: Hmmm that is strange in that the type of `v` gets inferred exactly as I typed it xD however I can't do this in my actual code, as the function comes from somewhere else and will be typed.

Comment: That's interesting. Trying to find explanation for such behavior

Answer (score 0):

So after playing around I managed to find a way to do what I needed, so putting it here in case it helps anyone else.

```js
class Foo<T> {
  constructor(public value: T, public fn: (value: Foo<T>) => void) {}
}

function makeFn<T extends number>(): (foo: Foo<T> & any) => void {
  return () => {};
}

const foo = new Foo(5, makeFn());
foo.value = 100;
```

This doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me, and is probably just fiddling with the specifics of how typescript infers types. I think there is a typescript bug with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options here:

**First**

```js
class Foo<T> {
  constructor(public value: T, public fn: (value: Foo<T>) => void) {}
}

const foo = new Foo<number>(5, (v: Foo<number>) => {});
foo.value = 100;
```

Second:

```js
class Foo<T> {
  constructor(public value: T, public fn: (value: Foo<T>) => void) {}
}

const foo = new Foo(5 as number, (v: Foo<number>) => {});
foo.value = 100;
```

**Third**

```js
class Foo<T> {
  constructor(public value: T, public fn: (value: Foo<T>) => void) { }
}

const x: number = 5;
const foo = new Foo(x, (v: Foo<number>) => { });
foo.value = 100;
```

**Fourth**

```js
class Foo<T> {
  constructor(public value: T, public fn: (value: Foo<T>) => void) { }
}


const foo = new Foo(5, (v) => { });
```

Because you don't have access to `Foo` you can't do much

Comment: Thanks for this, but it isn't useful in my case. What I really need is to not have to manually specify types when creating instances of `Foo`